# On MVC 5, after Signing In, Identity is still Unauthenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my login page, I have sign-in code like this ...

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

However, when I check User.Identity right after Signin, it is still Unauthenticated

`this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is returning false.

Anything I am missing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is not true until the next request. In my case I redirect to the Home/Index. Once inside HomeController.Index() method I see that IsAuthenticated == true.

From here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

> The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication information to the next request made by the browser.

Comment: Is IsAuthenticated true on the next request to the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using ASP.NET Identity.  Here is a working template and see whats different in your code.

Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    //
    // GET: /My/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /My/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid account name or password.");
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Page:

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "My", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="col-md-2 control-label"><strong>Account</strong></p>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" /> | @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "Explore")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct and I assumed IsAuthenticated is true after "await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);" but it is not ... why is that... ??